# How are these installed and how can I remove them?

Tags: fireplace, stone

New home.  Hate the tiny shelves.  Want to remove them, put a normal mantle in, and a TV above.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're putting a mantle in there you've got some major work ahead of you, and this is just a minor step. Taking those out is just a matter of chipping away the mortar around them with a suitable tool and cracking them loose. I doubt they have any additional fastening beyond the same mortar that holds the rest of the stone in place.

Comment: Use caution when removing those pieces and you can use them  to fill the holes , the mortar color will be off but their are ways of blending.